# private key for a secret code"1983"?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

[image]

Hi !! I tried to find information and examples to solve this **RSA cryptography with public and private keys** problem but couldn't find it.. This is my preparation questions for exam and not assignment.Could someone explain the steps to solve this problem? And, any resource with related examples like this? cheers!!

Comment: Call the private key, $d$. You find it by solving the congruence, $de\equiv1\bmod{(p-1)(q-1)}$.

Comment: And you solve any congruence like $ax \equiv 1 \bmod b$ using extended Euclid's algorithm for GCD, by finding $a^{-1} \bmod b$.

Comment: The question strikes me as very badly written.  Unless I grossly misunderstand RSA, the private key does not depend on the content of the message (clear or encrypted)!

Comment: @AntonSherwood, indeed, $p,q$ are no way "the public keys"!

Comment: $1983 = 3 \times 661$. OK, it's an RSA modulus (no $e$ though). But an unlikely one. This question is quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is what i did. However, I used wolfram alpha to calculate inverse 5 mod(1008) to find value of d but any ideas how can i do it using calculator or manually in exam? cheers!!

Comment: You can find $a^{-1} \bmod b$, where $GCD(a,b)=1$, using extended Euclidean algorithm. It yields integers $x,y$ s.t. $xa +yb = GCD(a,b)$. And it requires little calculations if one of $a,b$ is small, as in your case.

Comment: $1008\times3=3024$. $3024+1=3025$. $3025\div5=605$. So $5\times605\equiv1\bmod{1008}$, so $5^{-1}\equiv605\bmod{1008}$.